# Query to removeNon Alphabet characters from begining and end of a string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

as my table rows has data which is starting and ending with non alphabet char such as ".",";","," etc  . I need to remove them from the string . How can I do this ? I have done this using like statements there I need to search for each pattern and filter the. Is there any other better way ?

```
select lrno,free_text ,
(CASE 
 WHEN free_text LIKE ',%'   THEN SUBSTRING (free_text,2,len(free_text)-1)
 END) FREE_TEXT_TRIM
from vwLRClass3_FreeText 
ORDER BY PROPERTY_TEXT_VALUE
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

The Below function will remove other non alphabet chars from a string.

```
IF object_id('dbo.GetAlphachars') is not NULL
   DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNumeric 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAlphachars (@strAlphachars VARCHAR(256)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE  @intAlpha INT
SET      @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @strAlphachars )

BEGIN
WHILE    @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphachars  = STUFF(@strAlphachars, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @strAlphachars )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphachars ,0)
END
GO
```

Example.

```
CREATE table vish(val varchar(20));

INSERT into vish values('.,,.?ishhh>...,');

SELECT dbo.getalphachars(val) from vish;

result
------------
ishhh
```